# Confusion on State Provider in coffeescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angular-ui-router

New to Angular/Javascript:

I'm trying to remove an old coffeescript file (rent-roll.coffee) and replace it with rent-roll.js but am having an issue with the routing/state provider.

The existing routing works fine with the coffeescript file but I get the following error when I replace the old file:

Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'RentRollCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

The routing is set up as follows:

```
        .state 'manager.accounting.rent-roll',
        url: '/rent-roll'
        views:
            main:
                controller: 'RentRollCtrl'
                templateUrl: 'manager-dashboard/accounting/rent-roll/rent-roll.tpl.html'
```

I suspect I'm making a very elementary error related to having the routing come from a different file as I'm only used to very simple single-page routing.

My rent-roll.js code is as follows:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
angular
.module('roomchoice.manager-dashboard.accounting.rent-roll', [
  'ui.router'
])

.controller('RentRollCtrl', RentRollCtrl);

function RentRollCtrl($scope, Restangular) {}
```

etc. etc.

I understand that I'm doing something simple wrong in the controller instantiation but lack the conceptual understanding to understand what and the state provider docs weren't particularly helpful (or I missed something in them) any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your main Html page include `<script src="your controller js location"></script>` reference to the controller js file.

Additionally, You are creating a new angular module here. Hence check if you have included dependency in the main module. if not please add this module as a dependency on main module.

angular.module('your main module name', [add your dependecy here]);